# Mongoose Aggregate doesn't work without find() first

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Not sure exactly what's going on, but I have a `Model#aggregate()` call that works when it's preceded by a `Model#find()`, but not otherwise. This is the code I'm using (with dummy properties, `Thing` being my model object):

```
var query = { my_ids: { $in: _.pluck(this.related_ids, 'my_ids') } };

// This Thing.find is never executed and shouldn't ever be needed.
Thing.find(query);

Thing.aggregate([
    { $match: query },
    { $group: { _id: null, "amount": { "$sum": "$amount" } } },
]).exec(function(error, result) {
    // blah blah blah
});
```

When run as-is, it works as expected - the callback's result is `[{ _id: null, amount: <some number> }]` as expected. However, if the `Thing.find(query);` is commented out, it is just a blank array `[]`.

I know `Thing.find()` is returning a Query object and might be setting some state things in the background, which may be letting the `aggregate()` call finish, but it also doesn't work when the query is executed (which I'd assume would reset those state variables). I'm cool with leaving the `Thing.find(query)` call in to make it work for now, but it *does* make my eye twitch a little bit. Any thoughts?

Comment: Something else is going on as you certainly shouldn't need the `Thing.find` call there for `Thing.aggregate` to work.

Comment: That's what you'd think. And yet, here we are (I believe you, though...this is all the code in the function, but I'm sure there's something else affecting it.)

Comment: It actually sounds more and more like a race condition (where the `Thing.find()` just delays the `Thing.aggregate()` long enough for it to be in the database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, bit of a silly solution, but it's good to have answers to similar problems up on SO.

The problem: **race conditions**. The second I saw "this thing seems to affect an unrelated thing" while using Node.js, that's where my mind should have gone. This code happens immediately after some code where the objects are populated in the database (this is in a test), and there were some validation errors happening that weren't being caught. In any case, the objects weren't done being saved to the database, so with the slight delay of the `Thing.find()` call, it was delaying the aggregation until they were saved.